# Style posts based on custom fields in Wordpress?

Tags: php, css, wordpress, custom-fields

- I created a custom field in a post, called "post-class" and inserted the value "cita-flow800000".
- Called the new custom_value in my content-single.php in front of the post_class function, and inserted the variable inside the post_class function, like this:

`<article id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>" <?php post_class('class-1 class-2' . $custom_variable); ?>> <?php $custom_values = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'post_class'); ?>`

- Selected the class in my style.css:

`.cita-flow800000 {
    background-color: red;
}`

...and nothing happens. Can anyone help me spot where I missed the mechanism to achieve post stylling through different post classes?

I followed this recipe in this [blog post](http://www.wpbeginner.com/wp-themes/how-to-style-each-wordpress-post-differently/)

I tried changing the variable inside the post_class function into "$custom_values", thinking that "$custom_variable" could be a typo from the post that shared the recipe.

Answer (score 0):

This recipe worked out, after I tried 2 or 3 recipes for both the methods of calling the variables and functions in the content-single.php and through a functions.php filter.

https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/182736/69825 (check the Update#1 edit in the answer)

The code:

```
<?php $my_class = get_post_meta($post->ID, "your_meta_name") ?>
<div id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>" <?php post_class( $my_class ); ?>>
```

Basically, creating a variable $my_class determined by the post meta custom field (your_meta_name) and adding that variable to the post_class function inside the loop.